# Excel: Using "And" condition comparing derived values

Tags: excel

I have a spread sheet that has multiple divisions going down in rows, each row has one person and relevant information for the employees.  I have used a formula to eliminate all the duplicate divisions. I am trying to create summary information from the divisions.

My division were consolidated with the formula =INDEX($F$2:$F$587,MATCH(0,COUNTIF($J$1:J1,$F$2:$F$587),0))

Now I would like to use the derived value the corresponding Cell J2:J21 and count the row IF the value in F2:F588 is equal the value in the J cell AND the value in H2:H588 is equal to the value in Q1

This goal is to count how many persons in the organization are AMIND and total place the total number in the division.. I have tried a number or permutation but cannot seem to get it to work.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O5bal.png)

Comment: You want countifs()

Answer (score 1):

If I understood your question correctly what you want is:
**(1)** unique values of `Column F` are listed in `Column J`
**(2)** so first you want to match `Column F` to the values in `Column J`
**(3)** then match corresponding `Column H` values to `Cells N1, O1, P1, Q1, ....`
**(4)** for `(2)` and `(3)` conditions get the count under `Cells N1, O1, P1, Q1, ....`

If my understanding is correct then enter the following formula in `Cell N1`:

```
=COUNTIFS($F$2:$F$587,$J2,$H$2:$H$587,N$1)
```

and drag/copy this formula across and down as required.

See image below (with data till row 25):

[image]

Comment: @Mng; Thanks that worked .. I was not using an absolute reference, but that took care of it.

Comment: @Jux - Glad I could help.